# Suppose $f:[0,1] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\int_0^x f(x)dx = \int_x^1 f(x)dx$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $f:[0,1] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\int_0^x f(x)dx = \int_x^1 f(x)dx$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

So, I can intuitively see that this is true. My proof mostly makes sense, I think, but I'm not sure if it covers the case where there are negative and positive values in each segment, resulting in a *mean* value of 0, but still having nonzero values. Can someone tell me how to cover that, or how this does?

Suppose $f(x) \neq 0$ for all x $\in$ [0,1]. By the mean value theorem, there exist some c and d for which $f(c)(x) = f(d)(1-x) = \int_0^x f(x)dx$. Since x $\neq$ (1-x) for all x $\in$ [0,1], it follows that $f(c) = f(d) = 0$. Therefore, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Differentiate using FTC, to get $f(x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: Note that your $c,d$ depend on $x$. And that $1/2=1-1/2$.

Comment: Minor edit, but when you assume FSOC, negating 'for all' x results in 'for some' x

Comment: See also: [Show $f$ is constant zero function on $[a, b]$ if $\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_x^b f(t) dt \forall x \in [a, b].$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567147)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus proof suggested in a comment by Peter Tamaroff is one short line, and one cannot do better.

Here is a more awkward proof that does not use the FTC. Suppose that $f(x)\ne 0$ for some $x$. Say for example that $f(a)=c\gt 0$ for some $a$. By continuity we can assume that $a$ is not $0$ or $1$. Then there is an interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ contained in $(0,1)$ such that $f(x)\gt c/2$ in this interval.

Note that $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}\gt c\epsilon\gt 0$.

Let $x_1=a-\epsilon$, and $x_2=a+\epsilon$. Then if $\int_0^{x_1} f(t)\,dt=\int_{x_1}^1 f(t)\,dt$, we must have $\int_{0}^{x_2} f(t)\,dt \gt \int_{x_2}^1 f(t)\,dt$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another line of attack:

Since $\int_0^x f(t)dt = \int_x^1 f(t)dt$, we also have $\int_0^y f(t)dt = \int_y^1 f(t)dt$, so subtracting gives
$\int_0^y f(t)dt-\int_0^x f(t)dt = \int_y^1 f(t)dt-\int_x^1 f(t)dt$, or
$\int_x^y f(t)dt = \int_y^x f(t)dt = -\int_x^y f(t)dt$.

In other words, $\int_x^y f(t)dt = 0$ for all $x,y$.

Since $f$ is continuous, if $f(x_0) \neq 0 $ for some $x_0$, then there is some interval $[a,b]$ containing $x_0$ for which $|f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{2} |f(x_0)|$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. If follows that $\int_a^b f(t)dt \neq 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{%
\totald{}{x}\int_{0}^{x}{\rm f}\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi
=
\totald{}{x}\int_{x}^{1}{\rm f}\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi
\quad\imp\quad
{\rm f}\pars{x} = -{\rm f}\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad{\rm f}\pars{x} = 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

$\int_0^0 f(x)dx =0= \int_1^0 f(x)dx$ ; so that:

$(i) \int_0^x-\int_x^1=0$

Now, we also have:

$(ii)$ $\int_0^x+\int_x^1=\int_0^1=0$ (since $\int_1^0 f(x)dx=0)$

Taking these two:

$\int_0^x-\int_1^x=\int_x^1+\int_0^x$, we get $\int_0^x f(t)dt=0$ for all $x$

So that the function $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is constant in $x$.

Then $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)dt=f(x)=0$ for all $x$

Comment: $f$ is only defined on $[0, 1]$, so $\int_0^2 f$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just changed it.