# For continuous $f$, $\int_0^x f(t)dt = ∫_x^1f(t)dt$ implies $f=0$.

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $\int_0^x f(t)dt = ∫_x^1f(t)dt$ then prove that $f(x)=0$.

I suppose that $f(x)$ isn't zero, set $g(x)= \int_y^xf(t)dt$ with $y\in[0,1]$ and use Bolzano but I don't know if it's right.

Comment: See also: [Show $f$ is constant zero function on $[a, b]$ if $\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_x^b f(t) dt \forall x \in [a, b].$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567147) and [Suppose $f:[0,1] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\int_0^x f(x)dx = \int_x^1 f(x)dx$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/546535).

Answer (score 5):

From $\displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)\ dt = \int_x^1f(t)\ dt$ we can differentiate and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to obtain $f(x) = -f(x)$, whence $f(x) = 0$.