# Show $f$ is constant zero function on $[a, b]$ if $\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_x^b f(t) dt \forall x \in [a, b].$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I've started by trying to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and have that
$$\int_a^x f(t) dt - \int_x^b f(t) dt = 0$$
$$= F(x) - F(a) - (F(b) - F(x))$$
$$0 = 2F(x) - F(a) - F(b)$$
but am not sure how to proceed to show that $f$ is the constant zero function.

I saw this very similar question:   [Suppose $f:[0,1] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\int_0^x f(x)dx = \int_x^1 f(x)dx$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546535/suppose-f0-1-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continuous-and-int-0x-fxdx-i?rq=1), but am not sure how to form the "one line proof" using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus mentioned in the comments.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just differentiate both sides to get:

$$f(x)=-f(x)$$

for all $x$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Recall that the fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that for $f(x)$ continuous:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t) dt=f(x)$$
Then note that:

$$\int_x^b f(t) dt=-\int_b^x f(t) dt$$

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I kept trying to use only one form of the Fundamental Theorem.